# Apache Storm stream format

Tags: apache-storm

I am new to Apache Storm, but of course I know that the purpose is to process stream data. My question is: what are the requirements of the "stream", so that it can be processed by Storm using a sprout?
In my case I have an application written in C++, which I want to extend to generate stream data, that can be read from Storm. But how do I start with that, how can I create an interface for my application and how should the stream look like?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

As you know, Storm has the concept of spouts, that read data from some source and emit a stream of tuples to its bolts. The spout can be written to read from anything in any form, it's up to you to decide. There is an official implementation now to read from a Kafka server, but you can write something that fetch data from a database, a file or a network connection, as long as you implement it.

Between spout and bolts, data can pass in any form: basic types, strings, objects, arrays of bytes.